# how can I know current viewcontroller name in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have BaseView which implement UIViewController. Every view in project must implement this BaseView.

In BaseView, I have method:

```
-(void) checkLoginStatus
{
    defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];

    if(![[defaults objectForKey:@"USERID"] length] > 0 )
    {
        Login *login=[[Login alloc] initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:login animated:TRUE];
        [login release];
    }
    [defaults release];
}
```

The problem is my Login view also implement BaseView, checks for login, and again open LoginView i.e. stuck in to recursive calling.

Can I check in checkLoginStatus method if request is from LoginView then take  no action else check login. 
Ex:

```
- (void) checkLoginStatus
{
    **if(SubView is NOT Login){** 
        defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];

        if(![[defaults objectForKey:@"USERID"] length] > 0 )
        {
            Login *login=[[Login alloc] initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:login animated:TRUE];
            [login release];
        }
        [defaults release];
    }
}
```

Please help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following method:

```
if ([self isMemberOfClass:[Login class]])
{
    CFShow(@"Yep, it's the login controller");
}
```

`isMemberOfClass` tells you if the instance is an exact instance of that class. There's also `isKindOfClass`:

```
if ([self isKindOfClass:[BaseView class]])
{
    CFShow(@"This will log for all classes that extend BaseView");
}
```

isKind tests that the class is a extension of a certain class.

So given your example:

```
-(void) checkLoginStatus
{
    defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];

    if (![self isMemberOfClass:[Login class]])
    {
        if (![[defaults objectForKey:@"USERID"] length] > 0 )
        {
            Login *login=[[Login alloc] initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:login animated:TRUE];
            [login release];
        }
    }
    [defaults release];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

implement an empty checkLoginStatus in Login.

```
@implementation Login
  -(void) checkLoginStatus {}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one parameter in checkLoginStatus and set that parameter when you you call method from LoginView and in checkLoginStatus check that parameter if that parameter is set skip this block...i.e

```
if(![[defaults objectForKey:@"USERID"] length] > 0  && var1 != TRUE)
{
     Login *login=[[Login alloc] initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:login animated:TRUE];
    [login release];

}
```